# Ignoring sensitive files with .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

How to prevent exposure of sensitive files while keeping them in the local repository?

Scenario: I have sensitive files in my local repo. As a security measure, I specify those files in .gitignore file, so they are not pushed to the remote. A collaborator deletes my .gitignore file and pushes that change to the remote repo. I pull his changes. My sensitive files are not ignored anymore and I will push them accidentally to the remote. My sensitive files are now exposed.

Can scenario like this happen? How to prevent it?

Comment: Have you considered paying attention to what you're staging and committing? If you're just doing `git add .`, then: stop.

Comment: This is a personal accountability issue, not a technical one. Your collaborator needs a stern talking-to, and you need to be more careful.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to prevent this is to keep out sensitive data of your repository altogether.

Next best measure - which you should do any case - is to carefully review any changes before you commit them / check your committed changes before you push them.

If you really need to store sensitive information or local configurations within your repository you should discuss this with your team, where and how to store such data. Then the case that a *collaborator deletes my `.gitignore` file and pushes that change* should not happen without prior discussion and review by your team.

To ignore files in *your* local repository regardless of the `.gitignore` you can put it into the [`.git/info/exclude`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description) file of your local repository. This will ignore that file only in your local copy.

But be aware that neither of these measure protects you against pulling and executing code from untrustworthy sources^^

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a [pre-receive server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). That way, your policy is enforced on the server, and could reject any commits containing the "sensitive" files.